# Run powershell from powershell prompt with parameters

Tags: powershell, command-line

I am novice to power shell and I am not able to figure this very simple code out and have a question:

I have a basic script  c:\Folder\abc.ps1:

```
function abc 
{
Param( 
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false]
        $Env
}

Write-Output "The parameter is: $Env"
}
abc $Env
```

---

Now calling this script from command line:

```
C:\Dev> . "c:\Folder\abc.ps1" "Dev"
The parameter is:
C:\Dev> . "c:\Folder\abc.ps1" "Dev"
The parameter is:
```

Now if I initialize the Env then that works;

```
C:\Dev> $Env = "Dev"
C:\Dev> . "c:\Folder\abc.ps1"
C:\Dev> The parameter is: Dev
```

I would love to make this in one line like above from any location rather than the folder where it is placed.
I am using the Power shell from the Power shell prompt in Windows Environment

Your help is appreciated

Comment: Your first script does not accept arguments. That is why it does nothing when you pass it a string. Also avoid using `$env` as that is the same name as the environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options here.

You can call using the following statement to set the value of $Env

```
.\abc.ps1 -env "dev"
```

Or you can update your code to extract the values of the parameters you pass in which are unnamed. These are stored in an array called $args.

```
function abc 
{
}

$env=$args[0]

Write-Output "The parameter is: $env"
abc $env
```

And then call this function as

```
"c:\Folder\abc.ps1" "Dev"
```

Comment: Thanks , but there must be a way to run this from one command line and not setting it before. I am using a build system to run a power shell so unfortunately don't have that liberty.

Comment: @Akshay I don't understand why you think something like this does not work.

Comment: @Akshay Not exactly sure what you mean by 'setting it before'. Both of these options operate from one single command line.

Answer (score 0):

Your first script does *nothing* with the arguments being passed. That is why your first example does not net the output you expect. `$env` is always null.

On that topic do not use `$env` as a variable as it is the same as the provider used for environment variables. Albeit, that *has nothing to do with your issue*. Just know it is a something to avoid as it could be the cause of future issues or confusion.

The reason your second code call works is because using the [dot operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx).

> . Dot sourcing operator
>
> Runs a script in the **current scope** so that any functions,
>            aliases, and variables that the script creates are added to the current
>            scope.

If you want your first script to work you need to process arguments. The [answer by Alec Collier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33557937/3829407) covers a simple approach. Use the `$args` variable. There is several others and a notable one involves `param` just as you have used in your function.

```
Param( 
    [parameter(position=0,
        Mandatory=$false)]
    $bagel
)

function abc {
    Param( 
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        $value
    )

    Write-Output "The parameter is: $value"
}

abc $bagel
```

And then the script can be called just like you had.

```
. "c:\Folder\abc.ps1" "Dev"
```

Answer (score 0):

With a simple change from the `}` character to a `)` character, which seems to be a mistake on your part, your script should work absolutely fine.

I'm talking about this:

```
Param( 
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false]
    $Env
} <-------------
```

Notice how the open bracket is a round bracket, not a curly bracket. By putting a curly bracket you are closing the function, hence nothing works.